# How to download image using bitmapimage.save method

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have just added the text on the image. when I use the bitmapimage.save method it only show the image in the browser. But I want it automatically ask for downloading the image. I am using the below code.

```
      graphicImage.DrawString(TextBox1.Text,
      new Font("Times New Roman", 24, FontStyle.Bold),
      new SolidBrush(Color.White), new Point(200, 350));
      Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
      bitMapImage.Save (Response.OutputStream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

Comment: Can you provide a little more code?

Comment: ..................................................

Comment: How big is your original image. I just tried your code and it worked fine, except that I had to move the drawing point closer to the origin because of my image's dimensions. There is a chance your web server is returning a cached version of the image.

Comment: I can't say anything about it. But I am not getting any solution. Thanks for considering this problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Bitmap bitMapImage = new
       System.Drawing.Bitmap(Server.MapPath(imageurl));
    Graphics graphicImage = Graphics.FromImage(bitMapImage);
    graphicImage.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias; 
    graphicImage.DrawString(TextBox1.Text,
         new Font("Times New Roman", 24, FontStyle.Bold),
          new SolidBrush(Color.White), new Point(200, 350));
  Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
  bitMapImage.Save (Response.OutputStream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

Comment: Anyone have solution to this problem